# SQL GROUP BY after JOINs

Tags: sql, join, group-by

I'm trying to create a group by after a couple of joins. This is what I have tried below.

It gives an "unknown error" message without much context or info to troubleshoot from... I've tried multiple solutions I've found online and have referenced a few separate examples but have not had any luck. It seems quite basic to me so not sure what the issue is... I'm not a SQL expert as you can see...

For exta information, a slug is a unique identifier for each table. So an account slug is the id for the account, a season slug is the id for the season and so on.. There are not duplicate accounts or seasons in each table, so they are unique until the join.

The main column would be the account since there can only be one of those, then the seasons since one account can have many seasons, then the entries since one season can have many entries. My end goal is to get a count of all entries that have a submitted date per season per account. [Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/161ScPkjOVAr3-pn8wQoYMajFsUFlN9VWDNESr0w4FK8/edit?usp=sharing) is a google sheet with sample data.

I'm using ClicData's build in SQL tool, so that could potentially also be the issue.

Thanks for any help!

```
SELECT production_data.accounts.created_at AS account_created,
         production_data.accounts.id AS account_id,
         production_data.accounts.slug AS account_slug,
         production_data.seasons.id AS season_id,
         production_data.seasons.slug AS season_slug,
         production_data.seasons.created_at AS season_created,
         production_data.seasons.deleted_at AS season_deleted,
         production_data.entries.user_id AS user_id,
         production_data.entries.id AS entry_id,
         production_data.entries.slug AS entry_slug,
         production_data.entries.created_at AS entry_created,
         production_data.entries.deleted_at AS entry_deleted,
         production_data.entries.submitted_at AS entry_submitted,
         Count(production_data.entries.submitted_at)
FROM production_data.accounts
JOIN production_data.seasons
    ON production_data.accounts.id = production_data.seasons.account_id
JOIN production_data.entries
    ON production_data.seasons.id = production_data.entries.season_id
GROUP BY production_data.accounts.slug, production_data.seasons.slug
```

Comment: While we can tell you what's wrong with your query syntactically and how to fix it, we cannot do so semantically, because we don't know what the query is supposed to do. You group by a pair of slugs. This will get you one result row for each such pair. What are slugs? Is a slug unique in its table or can there be duplicates? It will help, if you add an explanation and some sample data along with the expected result.

Comment: Ok, got it, updated it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to count entries per account season. So you can show the account's data and the season's data, but not *the* entry's data, because there is no *the* entry. There can be *multiple* entries, which is why we count them.

```
SELECT 
  a.created_at AS account_created,
  a.id AS account_id,
  a.slug AS account_slug,
  s.id AS season_id,
  s.slug AS season_slug,
  s.created_at AS season_created,
  s.deleted_at AS season_deleted,
  COUNT(e.id) AS entry_count
FROM production_data.accounts a
JOIN production_data.seasons s ON s.account_id = a.id
JOIN production_data.entries e ON e.season_id = s.id
GROUP BY a.slug, s.slug
ORDER BY a.slug, s.slug;
```

You group by account slug and entry slug. You say that these columns are unique in their tables, so there are probably unique constraints on them. You are allowed then to select the account's data and the season's data, because your `GROUP BY` clauses makes sure you have one result row per account and season.

Some DBMS, though, demand that you group by the other columns, too, i.e. by `a.created_at` etc., because they don't manage too see that there can be just one `a.created_at` etc. per result row:

```
GROUP BY a.slug, s.slug, a.created_at, a.id, s.id, s.created_at, s.deleted_at
```

What I prefer anyway is to aggregate before joining. Here you want account seasons joined with their entry counts.

```
SELECT 
  a.created_at AS account_created,
  a.id AS account_id,
  a.slug AS account_slug,
  s.id AS season_id,
  s.slug AS season_slug,
  s.created_at AS season_created,
  s.deleted_at AS season_deleted,
  e.entry_count
FROM production_data.accounts a
JOIN production_data.seasons s ON s.account_id = a.id
JOIN
(
  SELECT season_id, COUNT(*) AS entry_count
  FROM production_data.entries
  GROUP BY season_id
) e ON e.season_id = s.id
ORDER BY a.slug, s.slug;
```

One more thing: Above queries don't show account seasons with zero entries. To get those account seasons, too, change the entry join to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` (or `LEFT JOIN` for short).

Comment: Thank you a lot for the solution and explanation! This got me to where I needed to get. I never considered aggregating before joining but it took me down a rabbit hole and was able to accomplish another couple of things.

Answer (score 0):

When you are grouping a result, you should include all the columns except the aggregate ones. Here is the updated query. This is syntactically correct, but I am not sure whether this serves your purpose.

```
SELECT production_data.accounts.created_at AS account_created,
         production_data.accounts.id AS account_id,
         production_data.accounts.slug AS account_slug,
         production_data.seasons.id AS season_id,
         production_data.seasons.slug AS season_slug,
         production_data.seasons.created_at AS season_created,
         production_data.seasons.deleted_at AS season_deleted,
         production_data.entries.user_id AS user_id,
         production_data.entries.id AS entry_id,
         production_data.entries.slug AS entry_slug,
         production_data.entries.created_at AS entry_created,
         production_data.entries.deleted_at AS entry_deleted,
         production_data.entries.submitted_at AS entry_submitted,
         Count(production_data.entries.submitted_at)
FROM production_data.accounts
JOIN production_data.seasons
    ON production_data.accounts.id = production_data.seasons.account_id
JOIN production_data.entries
    ON production_data.seasons.id = production_data.entries.season_id
GROUP BY production_data.accounts.created_at,
         production_data.accounts.id,
         production_data.accounts.slug,
         production_data.seasons.id,
         production_data.seasons.slug,
         production_data.seasons.created_at,
         production_data.seasons.deleted_at,
         production_data.entries.user_id,
         production_data.entries.id,
         production_data.entries.slug,
         production_data.entries.created_at,
         production_data.entries.deleted_at,
         production_data.entries.submitted_at
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use aggregate function on all the fields except Group by fields.

```
Select  Count(*),
        TripTrn.ClientId,
        TripTrn.SoldTo
From tbl_Trip As Trip
Inner Join tbl_TripTransaction As TripTrn on TripTrn.TripId = Trip.TripRowId
Group BY TripTrn.ClientId, TripTrn.SoldTo
```